# Binding in multilanguage WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, multilingual

I work on a Multi-Language application, everything is ok except the binding values, ex: In my user group table I have two fields `name` and `en_name`, I bind the `name` to a Textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding name}"/>
```

When I change the language of my application, How can I change the binding to `en_name`?

Comment: I don't that is a scalable approach for writing a multilingual application, what happens when you need an additional language ? you'll need to add more properties.
It's better to create a resx file for your strings, and create a different one for each language.

Comment: I think @Athul is correct. You should not create different variables for the language but you should update the `name` variable when changing a language and binging will update it in UI

Comment: Don't invent a wheel, look e.g. [here](https://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html) for markup extension solution.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041197/how-to-set-and-change-the-culture-in-wpf and the discussion of localization at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916510/are-windows-forms-old-tech

Answer (score 1):

> When I change the language of my application, How can I change the binding to en_name?

You don't. You change the *value* of the `name` source property to return the English name.

If you want to change the actual binding, you need to do this yourself programmatically:

```
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("en_name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Abdulsalam Elsharif,

this is the wrong approach ideally but if this is your requirement then I would suggest passing the current language and rename the column.

SELECT en_name as [name] from table;